# Infinite printing when structs point to each other

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I am writing an insertion function for a doubly-linked list in Common Lisp (sbcl), and setting two nodes to point at one another causes the result to print in an infinite loop. Why? What causes the node to be printed infinitely? How might I prevent an object from printing in this way?

Here is a minimal example (global vars used to keep things simple).

```
(defstruct node
  data
  next
  prev)

(defparameter *new* (make-node :data "hello"))
(defparameter *original* (make-node :data "world"))

(setf (node-prev *original*) *new*) ;; Prints fine.
(setf (node-next *new*) *original*) ;; INFINITE LOOP WHEN PRINTING!!!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it obvious? "setting two nodes to point at one another" -> it's circular. The printer prints one node, which prints the previous node, which prints the next node, which prints the previous node, which prints the next node, which prints the previous node, ...

The printer can be instructed to detect cycles. Use `cl:*print-circle*` set to T:

```
CL-USER 53 > (setf *print-circle* t)
T

CL-USER 54 > (setf (node-next *new*) *original*)
#1=#S(NODE :DATA "world"
           :NEXT NIL
           :PREV #S(NODE :DATA "hello" :NEXT #1# :PREV NIL))
```